# How to use prepared statement in a Hibernate query?

Tags: java, hibernate

How to use a prepared statement in a Hibernate query ?

Comment: You need learn more about `Hibernate Queries`. You can use `native SQL query`, create `named query` using `HQL`. Look at this http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-parameter-binding-examples/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default Hibernate uses `PreparedStatement`. You don't have to worry about it. Not only `Criteria` but Hibernate uses `PreparedStatement` for `createQuery` (HQL) and `createSQLQuery`.

**Edit**

```
Query spSQLQuery = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM user_master WHERE user_name = :param1");
spSQLQuery.setString("param1","vicky.thakor");
spSQLQuery.list();
```

**Update**

Use `setParameter` if `setString` is not there in `Query` interface.

Thank you @Agricola for the update.

Comment: SELECT gl_acc_no,SUM(case when debit_credit = '56' then local_currency end) Debit,
  SUM(case when debit_credit = '57' then local_currency end) Credit,
  count(case when debit_credit='57' then debit_credit end) CreditCount,
    count(case when debit_credit='56' then debit_credit end) DebitCount

  
FROM wee_fas_transaction_detail_det where document_no 
in('1643','1644','1645','1646','1647','1648','1649','1650','1651','1652','1653','1654','1655','1656','1657') 
GROUP BY gl_acc_no; This is my query how to return multiple coluumn values in java

Comment: If you are creating query by appending string then it'll be cached in same manner if some data changed in above query then it'll be cached again.. use `setParameter`, `setString`, etc...

Comment: can u give me example for this i can understand easly

Comment: Does it mean all queries in Hibernate are pre-compiled as PreparedStaetment?

Comment: setString has been deprecated since 5.2. The documentation recommends using setParameter instead.

Comment: In 5.6.2, Hibernate always calls `java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement` when creating queries. With exception of procedures which may use `prepareCall`. `createStatement` seems to be supported but never used. Note that whether any "prepared statement" features of your database are actually used, falls on your JDBC driver.