# createNativeQuery()& createQuery() with NamedParameter

Tags: hibernate, prepared-statement, jpql

I have an Entity `CategoryElement` :

```
@Entity(name = "CategoryElement ")
@Table(name = "category_element")
public class CategoryElement {
 
 @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(100)", name = "farsi_name",nullable = false)
 private String farsiName;

  /* and other stuff*/
```

I want to write a query for this entity same as we did  in `preparedStatement` but i got this Syntax Error `cannot resolve symbol`
There is my query:

```
public List<CategoryElement> findByName(String farsiName) {
    EntityManager manager = HibernateUtils.getEntityManager();
    Query query = manager.createQuery("select o from CategoryElement as o where o.farsi_name=:param");
    query.setParameter("param",farsiName);
    List categoryElementList = query.getResultList();
    manager.close();
    return categoryElementList;
}
```

I got the Syntax Error in line 3 : `cannot resolve symbol 'CategoryElement '` and also in line 4 I got the same message about `param`
I've tried the `CreateNativeQuery()` method like this :

```
Query query = manager.createNativeQuery("select * from category_element where farsi_name =: param", CategoryElement.class);  
query.setParameter("param",farsiName);
```

but again I got the same message in line 2 for `param`
I check with this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26405116/how-to-use-prepared-statement-in-a-hibernate-query)
but it doesn't solve my problem .
I have no idea .

EDIT:   I'm using jdk1.8 + tomcat 9 + Hibernate 5.4.27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try to replace this:

```java
@Entity(name = "CategoryElement ")
```

by this:

```java
@Entity(name = "CategoryElement")
```

I would suggest you completely remove `name` parameter in the `@Entity` annotation and leave just:

```java
@Entity
```

as by default `name` already equals to the unqualified name of the entity class.

2. As for your JPQL, I would suggest you to correct it in the following way:

```java
List<CategoryElement> categoryElementList = manager.createQuery(
   "select o from CategoryElement o where o.farsiName = :param",
   CategoryElement.class
)
.setParameter("param", farsiName)
.getResultList();
```

And several notes here:

- You should use entity field names in the JPQL, not table column names.
- It is better to avoid usage of [java raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). So, you should prefer to use those `EntityManager.createQuery` methods that return `TypedQuery<T>`

3. As for your native query, you can correct it in the following way:

```java
List<CategoryElement> categoryElementList = manager.createNativeQuery(
   "select * from category_element where farsi_name = :param",
   CategoryElement.class
)
.setParameter("param",farsiName)
.getResultList();
```

Comment: In the first way that you've suggested for JPQL format again I got that Syntax Error for `'param'`  in  `.setParameter("param",farsiName)`; and in a second way I have same problem with `CategoryElement` at this line  :`"select o from CategoryElement o where o.farsiName = :param"` ,  although I change the things you've mentioned in entity class. Finally I find the Answer with Positional Parameters . @SternK

Comment: What exactly Syntax Error do you get? Show full stack trace please.

Comment: Oh I made another mistake ... your solution is totally fine thanks a lot.